# NSFetchedResultsController doesn't update UITableView after launch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple UIManagedDocument-based Core Data app.  I'm new to programming in iOS and I've barely got it off the ground and I'm stuck.  I have People NSManagedObjects stored in Core Data.  When I first launch the app, no entries are there, but if I slide up a modal VC and dismiss it, they magically appear.  My design is loosely based on the "Photomania" app from the iTunes U/Sanford course, but with a singleton CoreDataStore object to handle getting the managedObjectContext.  This is the code for my CoreDataStore:

```
+ (CoreDataStore *)sharedStore
{
    static CoreDataStore *sharedStore = nil;
    if (!sharedStore)
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];

    return sharedStore;
}

+ (instancetype)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self sharedStore];
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)getContext
{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbDocument"];
    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
        NSLog(@"No file exists...");
        [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"Document saveForCreating completionHandler invoked. Success: %hhd", success);
            if (success) {
                self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
                NSLog(@"Got context for created file!!");
            }
        }];
    } else if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        NSLog(@"Document state is closed. documentState == %u", document.documentState);
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"Document opening success: %hhd", success);
            if (success) {
                self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
                NSLog(@"Got context for now-opened file!!");
            }
        }];
    } else {
        self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
        NSLog(@"Got context for already-opened file!!");
    }

    return self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

And here is the code from the PeopleListViewController:

```
- (void)setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    _managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
        request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                        ascending:YES
                                        selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
        request.predicate = nil;  // all Persons
        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    } else {
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!self.managedObjectContext)
        [self setManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataStore sharedStore] getContext]];
}
```

This is the result immediately after launch:

[image: After launch]

This is the modal VC:

[image: Modal VC]

This is after dismissing the modal VC (tapped Cancel):

[image: After Modal]

I've tried using performFetch on the managedObjectContext, even delaying it until well after the Core Data document reported it was opened.  Nothing works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory glance at your code, I noticed that you are creating your context asynchronously. That's great, but when that context is ready, you will need to inform the table view controller and have it call reloadData.

The completion handler in the data store will need to set the context property on the table view controller.

Comment: How would I do that.  I'm sure it's something that needs to go in the completion handler, but I'm not sure how I'd do it.  This sounds like it could be the issue.  I did a test and found that the `[fetchedObjects count]` is 0 initially, then 5 after dismissing the modal VC.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't magically update your tableView. I found Photomania a bit complex because of few assistant classes like CoreDataViewController. So tableVew may be reloaded only by calling `reloadData` method or using a pair `beginUpdates`-`endUpdates`. And `NSFetchedResultsController` may be updated only by calling `performFetch:` method.
I usually use `NSManagedObjectContext` getter:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (!_fetchedResultsController)
    {
        NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"some entity name"];
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"some predicate"];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" cacheName:nil];
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        NSError* error;
        [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Fetch ERROR. %@", error);
        }
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Here I set `NSFetechedResultsControllerDelegate` to self. And `performFetch:` to get data. And I realize delegate's methods:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I added a `performFetch:` at the end of `viewWillAppear`, but the results are the same.  `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` won't work because it's when the app starts.  No updates have been done.

Comment: @LouValencia, try to use `performFetch:` in `fetchedResultsController` setter. So you'll `performFetch:` when it will be necessary, for example, in `numberOfRowsInSection:`. If you storage will change, `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods will update your tableView